# Mysql error 1 from storage engine while querying table

Tags: mysql

I was trying to copy the database like we do in MS SQL server. so I google for it and I end with this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/mysql/where-does-mysql-stored-the-data-in-my-harddisk/comment-page-1/#comment-84282).

so I copied and pasted the folder for the data folder to data folder of another computer.

while I open the query Browser I was able to see the database and tables but when I query the table it shows the following error.

**got error 1 from storage engine**

Comment: How big is the whole database? Cannot you create a dump? PS: are OS and mysql version the same on both servers?

Comment: @Jacob you did see the link which I have given, that which I obtained by Google search.

Comment: @zerkms its a little DB and I just checking whether it is possible to do as we do in MS SQL Server. like just copy past the DB where ever you needed.

Comment: @Sathish Kumar k k: what table types in that db?

Comment: @zerkms I think you mean table engine... it is InnoDB

Comment: Have you checked http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-backup.html ?